# Spaghetti plot using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, timeserieschart

I would like to produce a speghatii `plot` where i need to see days of the year on the `x-axis` and data on the `y-axis` for each `Year`. I would then want a separate year that had data for only 3 months `(PCPNewData)` to be `plotted` on the same `figure` but different `color` and `bold` line. Here is my `sample code` which produce a graph (attached) where the data for each `Year` for a particular `Day` is `stacked`- i don't want `bar` graph. I would like to have a `line` graph. Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)

myDates=as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), to=as.Date("2010-12-31"),by="days"))
colnames(myDates) = "Date"
Dates = myDates %>% separate(Date, sep = "-", into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"))

LatestDate=as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), to=as.Date("2011-03-31"),by="days"))
colnames(LatestDate) = "Date"
NewDate = LatestDate %>% separate(Date, sep = "-", into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"))

PCPDataHis = data.frame(total_precip = runif(4018, 0,70), Dates)
PCPNewData = data.frame(total_precip = runif(90, 0,70), NewDate)

PCPDataHisPlot =PCPDataHis %>% group_by(Year) %>% gather(key = "Variable", value = "Value", -Year, -Day,-Month)

ggplot(PCPDataHisPlot, aes(Day, Value, colour = Year))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data = PCPNewData, aes(Day, total_precip))
```

[image]

I would like to have a Figure like below where each line represent data for a particular year
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I draw my desired `figure` with hand (see attached). I would like to have all the `days of the Years` on `x-axis` with its data on the `y-axis`
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example that doesn't rely on the `weathercan` package. I think your problem has nothing to do with that specific package, and the idea of a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) is to leave everything out that is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks- I just updated the question as suggested.

Comment: Excellent! And as you can see, as soon as you posted a MRE , you immediately got a good answer! (I'm assuming now that was due to the MRE, I might be wrong ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few errors in your code.

First, your days are in `character` format. You need to pass them in a numerical format to get line being continuous.

Then, you have multiple data for each days (because you have 12 months per year), so you need to summarise a little bit these data:

```r
Pel2 <- Pelly2Data %>% group_by(year,day) %>% summarise(Value = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE))
  Pel3 <- Pelly2_2011_3months %>% group_by(year, day) %>% summarise(total_precip = mean(total_precip, na.rm = TRUE))


ggplot(Pel2, aes(as.numeric(day), Value, color = year))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_line(data = Pelly2_2011_3months, aes(as.numeric(day), y= total_precip),size = 2)
```

[image]

It looks better but it is hard to apply a specific color pattern

To my opinion, it will be less confused if you can compare mean of each dataset, such as:

```r
library(tidyverse)
Pel2 <- Pelly2Data %>% group_by(day) %>% 
    summarise(Mean = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE),
                           SEM = sd(Value,na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())) %>%
    mutate(Name = "Pel_ALL")
Pel3 <- Pelly2_2011_3months %>% group_by(day) %>% 
    summarise(Mean = mean(total_precip, na.rm = TRUE),
                           SEM = sd(total_precip, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())) %>%
    mutate(Name = "Pel3")

Pel <- bind_rows(Pel2,Pel3)

ggplot(Pel, aes(x = as.numeric(day), y = Mean, color = Name))+
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Mean-SEM, ymax = Mean+SEM), alpha = 0.2)+
    geom_line(size = 2)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: New graph based on update**

To get the graph you post as a drawing, you need to have the day of the year and not the day of the month. We can get this information by setting a date sequence and extract the day of the year by using `yday` function from `lubridate package.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
Pelly2$Date = seq(ymd("1990-01-01"),ymd("2010-12-31"), by = "day")
Pelly2$Year_day <- yday(Pelly2$Date)

Pelly2_2011_3months$Date <- seq(ymd("2011-01-01"), ymd("2011-03-31"), by = "day")
Pelly2_2011_3months$Year_day <- yday(Pelly2_2011_3months$Date)

Pelly2$Dataset = "ALL"
Pelly2_2011_3months$Dataset = "2011_Dataset"

Pel <- bind_rows(Pelly2, Pelly2_2011_3months)
```

Then, you can combine both dataset and represent them with different colors, size, transparency (alpha) as show here:

```r
ggplot(Pel, aes(x = Year_day, y = total_precip, color = year, size = Dataset, alpha = Dataset))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_size_manual(values = c(2,0.5))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1,0.5))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thank you. I would like to see which yearly pattern the newData (which in our case is year 2011) will follow. Based on this, i can then predict what we shall expect in april-December of the year 2011. I understand there is larger uncertainty but it will hint out some signals what the future may have.

Comment: I edited my answer to get closer to the drawing you have posted

Comment: thumbs up :) - appreciated.